# Softlayer - How to find the hardware server's image reference code by its image name

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can I find out the  hardware server's image reference code by its image name ? 
I tried searching the image `Vyatta Subscription Edition for Bare metal 6.7.9` and `VMware VSphere 6.5.0u1` [here](https://control.softlayer.com/devices/images) but did not find the image. Used the ruby gem to find out the images by following code

```
SoftLayer::ImageTemplate.find_public_templates(:name => name, client: client).first
```

But it was not able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched on my account and couldn't see any public image templates provided by SoftLayer with the names `Vyatta Subscription Edition for Bare metal 6.7.9` or `VMware VSphere 6.5.0u1`.

Image templates can be created from virtual guests only, so if you create and make them public then they should be listed here https://control.softlayer.com/devices/images, the portal page makes api calls to retrieve that list, the [getPublicImages](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getPublicImages/) retrieves the public images and [getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups/) the private ones

I can suggest you to use object-filters to search images which their name starts with "Vyatta", the filter is something like this:

```rb
filter = SoftLayer::ObjectFilter.new do |img_filter|
    img_filter.accept('name').when_it begins_with('Vyatta')
end
```

Then your code should looks like the following:

```rb
SoftLayer::ImageTemplate.find_public_templates(:object_filter => filter)
```

It seems the `find_public_templates` takes a long time when retrieving the data with  object_filter so I can also suggest you my own script which I feel it retrieves the data a little faster:

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'    
require 'pp'

username = 'set me'
api_key = 'set me'

image_service = SoftLayer::Service.new('SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group',
                                         username: username, api_key: api_key)

filter = SoftLayer::ObjectFilter.new do |img_filter|
    img_filter.accept('name').when_it begins_with('Vyatta')
end

# Another way to set filters: 
# filter = SoftLayer::ObjectFilter.new
# filter.set_criteria_for_key_path("name", "operation"=>"^= Vyatta")

begin
  images = image_service.object_filter(filter).getPublicImages
  pp images
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "Error when executing the script... #{e}" 
end
```